# how to make a description appear when hovering the menu?

Tags: html, css

I have the following image of a trophy on my main page and I would like to make a small description appear when a user hovers over it just as on this site. When I hover over the icons on the top right, I can see some description. Is this done through onclick? It looks neater than just having a paragraph description....

Answer (score 1):

It would be done using onMouseOver to call the function to display or update the element that shows the description. See below example

```
<a href='link.html' onMouseOver='showDescription();'><img src='icon.png'></a>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you need to use a function for onMouseOver? Can I replace it with text? onMouseOver='see your rewards'; etc? thanks!

Comment: onMouseOver allows you to call a function or update text in an element. But for a more simple approach is use the title parameter like this <a href='link.html' title='Link Hover Text'>

Comment: I am using font awesome for an image and this is my code:

Comment: echo "<div class='trophy'><i class='fas fa-trophy fa-5x'></i><a href='trophy.php' title='Click here to view your rewards'></a></div>";

Comment: This might be to do with the parent elements CSS display properly.

Comment: Try change the background-color property to red to confirm that's this is the case. But you could try display: block or display: inline to fix

Comment: I just realised that I have a duplicate body{} and hence it wasn't changing color that I wanted but maybe my codee is wrong but it should be a clickable image instead of an anchor? The image has shifted to the side to display the anchor

Comment: I did update my image but is it still been approved because I can't see the image? I can get the image to stop moving by adding position: fixed..I am new to position fixed but it seems that I can't use top, left or right, as it won't move the object... can we use the top, left or right with fixed?

Comment: should I upload another image?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `title` attribute.

```html
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50" title="some text">
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance but for some reason, it is showing a white box when I hover over it as shown in this image...

Comment: Have you added any text to the title?

Comment: I have and I also thought that I uploaded a picture of it... Can you guys see any pic?

Comment: the picture was there the other day but there is still a white square beside it

Comment: Am I meant to be seeing a white square box?

Comment: @piano0011 Please update your question with the code you are using, an image of what you want, and an image of what's happening. We'll be able to help you better then, thanks